# Merge and Dedupe Array of Complex Objects with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a pretty complex problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have two array of objects that I would like to merge scores for. It should merge/append certain properties based on the scores. For example between the two arrays there are 4 total `gameId`'s with 3 of them being unique. When merging it should combine the `_scores` section if it's the same `gameId` so in this case it would be both `EarthNormal` merging. But the problem is sometimes the `score` in `_scores` can have duplicate scores so the BAR and BASH almost look the exact same but are different it can be appended but `FOO` score is the exact same on both so I don't want it merged into the scores (if that makes sense).

```js
const arr1 = [{
  "gameId": "AirNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 144701,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": true,
      "timestamp": 1599968866
    }]
}, {
  "gameId": "EarthNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 177352,
      "playerName": "BAR",
      "fullCombo": true,
      "timestamp": 1599969253
    }, {
      "score": 164665,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": false,
      "timestamp": 1599970971
    }]
}];

const arr2 = [{
  "gameId": "EarthNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 177352,
      "playerName": "BASH",
      "fullCombo": false,
      "timestamp": 1512969017
    }, {
      "score": 164665,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": false,
      "timestamp": 1599970971
    }]
}, {
  "gameId": "FireNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "_score": 124701,
      "_playerName": "FOO",
      "_fullCombo": true,
      "_timestamp": 1591954866
    }]
}];
```

I would want the final merged array to look like:

```js
mergedArray = [{
  "gameId": "AirNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 144701,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": true,
      "timestamp": 1599968866
    }]
}, {
  "gameId": "EarthNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 177352,
      "playerName": "BAR",
      "fullCombo": true,
      "timestamp": 1599969253
    }, {
      "score": 177352,
      "playerName": "BASH",
      "fullCombo": false,
      "timestamp": 1512969017
    }, {
      "score": 164665,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": false,
      "timestamp": 1599970971
    }]
}, {
  "gameId": "FireNormal",
  "_scores":
    [{
      "score": 124701,
      "playerName": "FOO",
      "fullCombo": true,
      "timestamp": 1591954866
    }]
}]
```

I have tried doing this and using `lodash`:

```js
let merged = [...arr1, ...arr2];

merged = _.uniqBy[merged, 'gameId']
let scoresMerge = _.uniqBy[merged, '_scores']

console.log(scoresMerge);
```

but it didn't work as I expected. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward using vanilla javascript.

- merge the arrays using destructuring
- `reduce()` the merged arrays into an object indexed by `gameId`
- check all properties of each `_score` object against the accumulated `_scores` array using `.some()` and push if no match is found.
- return the values of the reduced object using `Object.values()`

```js
const arr1 = [{  "gameId": "AirNormal",  "_scores":    [{      "score": 144701,      "playerName": "FOO",      "fullCombo": true,      "timestamp": 1599968866    }]}, {  "gameId": "EarthNormal",  "_scores":    [{      "score": 177352,      "playerName": "BAR",      "fullCombo": true,      "timestamp": 1599969253    }, {      "score": 164665,      "playerName": "FOO",      "fullCombo": false,      "timestamp": 1599970971    }]}];

const arr2 = [{"gameId": "EarthNormal","_scores":[{"score": 177352,"playerName": "BASH","fullCombo": false,"timestamp": 1512969017}, {"score": 164665,"playerName": "FOO","fullCombo": false,"timestamp": 1599970971}]}, {"gameId": "FireNormal","_scores":[{"_score": 124701,"_playerName": "FOO","_fullCombo": true,"_timestamp": 1591954866}]}];


const merged = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((a, {gameId, _scores}) => {
  // retrieve gameId object otherwise initialize it.
  a[gameId] = {...a[gameId] ?? {gameId, _scores: []}};
  // iterate over all _score objects
  _scores.forEach(s => {
    // if accumulator _scores array doesn't have an object matching all properties, push _score 
    if (!a[gameId]['_scores'].some(o => {
        return !Object.entries(s).some(([k, v]) => o[k] !== v)})
      ) {
      a[gameId]['_scores'].push({...s});
    }
  });  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify objects with the same `gameId`, and then concat and dedupe their `_.scores` array.

It's easy to concat/dedup non primitive array items using `Array.reduce()` and a Map. For every item you check if the requested key is already in the Map. If it's not, you assign the current item to the Map's key. If it is you replace / merge the current item with the item in the Map.

After you finish iterating the Map, use `Array.from()` to convert the Map's `.values()` iterator to an array.

```js
const arr1 = [{"gameId":"AirNormal","_scores":[{"score":144701,"playerName":"FOO","fullCombo":true,"timestamp":1599968866}]},{"gameId":"EarthNormal","_scores":[{"score":177352,"playerName":"BAR","fullCombo":true,"timestamp":1599969253},{"score":164665,"playerName":"FOO","fullCombo":false,"timestamp":1599970971}]}];
const arr2 = [{"gameId":"EarthNormal","_scores":[{"score":177352,"playerName":"BASH","fullCombo":false,"timestamp":1512969017},{"score":164665,"playerName":"FOO","fullCombo":false,"timestamp":1599970971}]},{"gameId":"FireNormal","_scores":[{"score":124701,"playerName":"FOO","fullCombo":true,"timestamp":1591954866}]}];

const dedupLastBy = (a1 = [], a2 = [], key) => Array.from(
  [...a1, ...a2].reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const keyName = obj[key];
  
    if(acc.has(keyName)) acc.delete(keyName);
  
    return acc.set(keyName, obj);
  }, new Map()).values()
)

const handleDups = ({ _scores: a, ...o1 }, { _scores: b, ...o2 }) => ({
  ...o1,
  ...o2,
  _scores: dedupLastBy(a, b, 'playerName')
});

const result = Array.from([...arr1, ...arr2]
  .reduce((acc, o) => {
    const { gameId } = o;
    
    if(acc.has(gameId)) acc.set(gameId, handleDups(acc.get(gameId), o));
    else acc.set(gameId, o);
    
    return acc;
  }, new Map()).values());

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```